# snowflake parquet load schema generation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

Working on loading parquet file to snowflake table from S3 location. This is what I am doing:

1. created target table

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.target_table(
 col1 DATE,
 col2 VARCHAR);
```

2. Created stage table using the following command

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY STAGE myschema.stage_table 
   url = 's3://mybucket/myfolder1/' 
 storage_integration = My_int 
 fileformat = (type = 'parquet')
```

3. Load the target table from the stage table

```
COPY INTO myschema.target_table FROM(
  SELECT $1:col1::date,
         $1:col2:varchar
  FROM myschema.stage_table)
```

This works fine, my issue is, I have 10s of tables with 10s of columns. Is there any way to optimize the step 3, where I dont have to explicitly mention column names, so that code will become generic:

```
 COPY INTO myschema.target_table FROM(
  SELECT *
  FROM myschema.stage_table)
```

Comment: Will you be able to convert the parquet into CSV on AWS using Glue. More cost but if you can use CSV, you will not have to mention the columns

Comment: @Thelight could you share your generic solution if you got one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try
**MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME** = CASE_SENSITIVE | CASE_INSENSITIVE | NONE

Document: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-parquet

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFER_SCHEMA and TEMPLATE over ARRAY_AGG to generate the table based on the stage. To avoid this bombing out due to column metadata size limits you can base your inference on the first file in the stage location

```
SET FIRST_FILENAME_IN_STAGE = 
(SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME, '/', -1) 
FROM @MY_STAGE(file_format => aws_parquet) limit 1);

SET PATH_OF_FIRST_FILE_NAME = '@MY_STAGE' || $FIRST_FILENAME_IN_STAGE;


CREATE OR REPLACE  EXTERNAL TABLE MY_TABLE_EXTERNAL
  USING TEMPLATE (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
    FROM TABLE(
      INFER_SCHEMA(
        LOCATION=>$PATH_OF_FIRST_FILE_NAME,
        FILE_FORMAT=>'aws_parquet'
      )
    )
  )
  LOCATION=@MY_STAGE
  FILE_FORMAT=aws_parquet
  AUTO_REFRESH=false;
```